# Writing in multiple unrelated tables in spring batch writer

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Can we have a writer which will write in 2 different unrelated tables simultaneously in spring batch? Actually, Along with the main data I need to store some metadata in a different table. How can I go about it?

Comment: Please use Composite writer this can add  sequence of tables and any failure will be fully roll backed. This will be cleaner approach as the transactions will be handled perfectly. Let me know code snippet is required

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Can you please provide some code snippet?

Comment: Added in the answer section. Please let me know if you face any issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below . Let say you have 3 tables to write

```
@Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter compositeWriter() throws Exception {
        CompositeItemWriter compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter();
        List<ItemWriter> writers = new ArrayList<ItemWriter>();
        writers.add(firstTableWriter());
        writers.add(secondTableWriter());
        writers.add(thirdTableWriter());
        compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(writers);
        return compositeItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourDTO> firstTableWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourDTO> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseItemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO FIRSTTABLE");
        ItemPreparedStatementSetter<YourDTO> invoicePreparedStatementSetter = new FirstTableSetter();
        databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(invoicePreparedStatementSetter);
        return databaseItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourDTO> secondTableWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourDTO> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseItemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO SECOND TABLE");
        ItemPreparedStatementSetter<YourDTO> invoicePreparedStatementSetter = new SecondTableSetter();
        databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(invoicePreparedStatementSetter);
        return databaseItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourDTO> thirdTableWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourDTO> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchCustomItemWriter<>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseItemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO THIRD TABLE");
        ItemPreparedStatementSetter<YourDTO> invoicePreparedStatementSetter = new ThirdTableSetter();
        databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(invoicePreparedStatementSetter);
        return databaseItemWriter;
    }

    //SettterClass Example
    public class FirstTableSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<YourDTO> {
    

    @Override
    public void setValues(YourDTO yourDTO, PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, yourDTO.getMyValue());
    }
    }
```